# Does this question work with Bayes formula?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

Looking at slide 11, Example 1.10  from:
http://www-users.aston.ac.uk/~cornford/probmod/ProbMod310810_Ch1.pdf

> Luke has been told he’s lucky and has won a prize in the lottery.
>   There are 5 prizes available of value £10, £100, £1000, £10000,
>   £1000000. The prior probabilities of winning these 5 prizes are $p_1,
> > p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$, with $p_0$ being the prior probability of winning
>   no prize.
>
> Luke asks eagerly ‘Did I win £1000000?!’. ‘I’m afraid not sir’, is the
>   response of the lottery phone operator. ‘Did I win £10000?!’ asks
>   Luke. ‘Again, I’m afraid not sir’.
>
> What is the probability that Luke has won £1000?

I assume Bayes' formula would work here: $P(x\mid j) = \dfrac{P(j\mid x)P(j) }{ P(x)}$

If so, I see how the denominator in their answer:
 $P(w \neq 5, w \neq 4, w \neq 0)$ comes from

***but I am not able to figure out how they got the numerator:*** $p(w=3, w \neq 5, w \neq 4, w \neq 0)$

any help is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an application of Bayes formula, but just a standard conditional probability problem. Recall for events $A$ and $B$ that $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$. Now take $A$ to be the event $W = 3$, and $B$ the event $W \neq 4, W \neq 5, W \neq 0$.

Comment: @AWertheim: so applying Bayes formula here would give us a different answer but mean the same thing?